# Prevent SplashScreen display after rotate screen

Tags: android, android-splashscreen

I have `SplashScreen` with fade animation like this.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener { splashScreenProvider ->
            val fadeAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                splashScreenProvider.view, View.ALPHA, 1f, 0f
            )
            fadeAnim.duration = 500L
            fadeAnim.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator()
            fadeAnim.doOnEnd { splashScreenProvider.remove() }
            fadeAnim.start()
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

theme

```
<style name="Theme.MySplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#000</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_baseline_play_arrow_24</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>

    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

It working well when launch the application. However, when I rotate the screen, the `SplashScreen` display again.
If I remote the fade animation, `SplashScreen` working well (it won't display after rotate screen).

[image]

How can I prevent `SplashScreen` display after rotate screen without remove the fade animation?

Comment: add this line,may this helpful.`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

Comment: @EAS in my case, because I support tablet and I have different layout for tablet so I can not use configChanges="orientation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the state of animation, lets say, a boolean `isPlayed`. Set it to true when the animation plays and save the sate using `savedInstanceState`. Inside `onCreate`, create a `if-check` and only play animation if it is not played.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think just checking `savedInstanceState` != null in `onCreate` is enough (without saving `isPlayed` boolean)?

Comment: Yeah, that should work as well. But i would prefer to make the boolean just to make sure that we are not referring to something else (if there are other stuffs that you're storing) and is more readable in the code as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check if `savedInstanceState` is `null`

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
            splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener { splashScreenProvider ->
                val fadeAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    splashScreenProvider.view, View.ALPHA, 1f, 0f
                )
                fadeAnim.duration = 500L
                fadeAnim.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator()
                fadeAnim.doOnEnd { splashScreenProvider.remove() }
                fadeAnim.start()
            }
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```